# Unable to install google chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, installation

I've been trying to install .deb chrome file (google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb) but unable to do. I only get the message saying that "It is not installable" and "Some packages could not be installed".

logs:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Unsupported file ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb given on commandline
```

Note, selecting 'google-chrome-stable:amd64' instead of './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

```
google-chrome-stable:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not installable                                                                         
                          Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installable 
Recommends:: command not found
ubuntu@ip-:~$ E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E:: command not found
```

Comment: I think you should ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4):

Try this method worked for me

Navigate to the folder were google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb is present

Example:     `cd/Downloads/`

Run this code `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

If you encounter any problem run `sudo apt install -f`

And re run the below code

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

By running the above code Google-chrome will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

To install the package use command like:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb
```

This will install also dependencies.

Comment: This gives an error  " Unsupported file ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb given on commandline"

Comment: @Jhanvi, so you download a wrong file (architecture of processor for example). CHeck the architecture, download proper file and try again